How to define type of export default arrow function?
How do I define the type of an export default arrow function?
For example, I have tried:
export default ({ title, children }): Component => {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <title>{title}</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold underline">Hello world!</h1>
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};

I know that I can declare a const, but I'm looking for a solution like this if possible.
I'm expecting to be able to type the arrow function without assigning it to a const if possible.

You can't. Either assign the const, or just use function here. export default function MyComponent ({ title, children }): Component  { ... }

You could use export default (() => {}) as React.FC;

He could but its best not to do that as casting doesn't have the same type safety semantics as assigning the type and so probably shouldn't be done routinely. For example that exact snippet would compile and it really ought not to since Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.  due to missing return type in this case, but casting can evade all sorts of things you don't want to evade as a matter of course.

"For example, I have tried" - and does that not work? Component is the properly declared return type. Now just add a parameter type declaration and you're set.

How would you do it with a const? It's not quite clear what you are looking for.

Just some cents based on my experience: default exports only have downsides instead of upsides 9 out of 10 times.
export const is way easier to read and maintain. Why is this not an option for you?

You're looking for ms/TS#13626 but it's not implemented. See that issue and the linked q/a above for more information.

@adsy Well satisfies can be used too. It was just an example.
